# postgres single column btree index vs multi column index for single column use case

Tags: postgresql

Given that I have an index

`create index idx_a on table_a (a)`

If I now add more columns to that index, any maybe also include some data in the leaf blocks like so:

`create index idx_a on table_a (a,b,c,d desc) include (e,f)`

How much worse (in terms of speed and blocks that need to be read etc...) does this index get for all the use cases where I only need column `a` ?

Examples:

`select * from table_a where a = 5`
`select * from table_a where a < 10` ...

I tried to read up on how postgres stores a multicolumn index, but could not find an explanation. There seem to be different ways to store a multicolumn index and in some ways adding columns might not matter (additional colums are stored via additional btree indexes starting on the leaf blocks of the first column) and in some ways it might matter a lot (combination of all index columns becomes key of one common btree).

I'd be interested in both an answer to the concrete example, but would also be grateful if you could point me to a great article how postgres stores multi column btrees exactly.

Comment: You have to run your own benchmark on realistic data to get a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer heavily depends on the characteristics of your data set, what your typical traffic is, and whether you're considering the *much worse* in the overall table access context, or from the perspective of each individual query.

Expanding the index will of course affect the simpler queries but if they don't dominate how the table's typically accessed, it might be worth it.

You can also eat the cookie and have it too, by keeping both of these around. The queries will switch between them: [demo on 400k integers](https://dbfiddle.uk/M-3V8M-q)

```sql
create table table_a(a int,b int,c int,d int,e int,f int);

select setseed(.42);
insert into table_a 
select random()*1e3, random()*1e3, random()*1e3,
       random()*1e3, random()*1e3, random()*1e3
from generate_series(1,4e5,1);

create index idx_a on table_a (a);
```

Now, the other one's added next to the old one, without replacing it:

```sql
create index idx_a2 on table_a (a,b,c,d desc) include (e,f);
```

Note how the query that selects `*` will use the wide one, and the one targetting only `a` will revert to the narrow one.

```sql
explain analyze select * from table_a where a < 10;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Index Only Scan using **idx_a2** on table_a (cost=0.42..133.13 rows=3469 width=24) (actual time=0.010..0.626 rows=3903 loops=1) |
| Index Cond: (a < 10) |
| Heap Fetches: 0 |
| Planning Time: 0.064 ms |
| Execution Time: 0.763 ms |

This one selects only the single column so it switches to the narrow index on its own:

```sql
explain analyze select a from table_a where a < 10;
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Index Only Scan using **idx_a** on table_a (cost=0.42..77.13 rows=3469 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.333 rows=3903 loops=1) |
| Index Cond: (a < 10) |
| Heap Fetches: 0 |
| Planning Time: 0.043 ms |
| Execution Time: 0.466 ms |

Comment: To get proper, reliable, repeatable, averaged-out tests, you can run [`pgbench`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgbench.html). It has some built-in scripts, or you can create a new one with the queries you're optimising against.

Comment: ty - I understand now that this question can't be answered 'in general'. I'd still be very interested in a link to a page where it is explained how a btree in postgres looks under the hood in terms of data structure and access of that structure. If anyone has a good link - please share it here.

Comment: In general, if you're tempted to look under the hood there's [`pageinspect`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html#PAGEINSPECT-B-TREE-FUNCS). Concepts related to indexes are in [*Chapter 11. Indexes*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes.html) but I'm guessing you'll be interested in [how Postgres goes from getting a query to executing stuff](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/overview.html). You can also take a look at [the source](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/access/nbtree/README).